# Logging read access to SVN?

Tags: svn

Is there a way to log read accesses to an svn repo ? Any SVN configs (or tools/scripts) which can do this ?

I found svn-access-manager, but not sure if it logs access. Also, it requires a mysql/apache setup. Something that writes to a file would be fine.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache's log is what you want.  Subversion itself doesn't log access separately.

Answer (score 8):

Logging is only available in apache. In apache you can either use the cryptic access.log with each single WebDAV-Request or you can use a more svn specific log:

To enable a log which will log only subversion actions, place a directive like this *outside* your location:

```
CustomLog logs/svn_logfile "%t %u %{SVN-ACTION}e" env=SVN-ACTION
```

Look here for more details:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.logging

More on the apache variable available in logfile:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats

Answer (score 6):

Although its very old question but as svn access log solution was never presented and question is never closed, here is the solution that is not tied to Apache.

Use --logfile option in server startup script, you can get all the access log. Logs includes time, IP address, repository, user, and command (log, update, commit etc).

usr/bin/svnserve -d --listen-port=$SVN_PORT --log-file $SVN_LOG_FILE --pid-file=$SVN_PIDFILE

This is a global log for all the repositories, but you can always filter based on repository.
It will log when you access the repository using svn protocol.

I hope this helps.

Comment: `svnserve` isn't used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Apache access.log seems to have what I want. Not sure if there are any better alternatives. Will wait for suggestions for a while before closing the question.